# How to use graphical tilesets in Angband in Linux?

Tags: linux

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to use any of the included graphical tilesets in Angband 3.5.1, nor can I seem to use Shockbolt's tilesets.

For example, all the following commands launch into an ASCII interface:

```
/usr/games/angband -g -msdl -- -b -g
/usr/games/angband -g -msdl
/usr/games/angband -g
```

I have the following installed:

```
 % ls -l /usr/share/angband/xtra/graf
total 1964
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  481403 May  3  2018 16x16.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1317253 May  3  2018 32x32.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   38254 May  3  2018 8x16.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  159717 May  3  2018 8x8.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1393 May  3  2018 graphics.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    2274 May  3  2018 mr_att.png
```

and I have installed:

```
 % ls -l /usr/share/angband/xtra/shockbolt 
total 5596
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4941574 Feb 23 14:20 32x32.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   49314 Feb 23 14:28 64x64.png
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  232548 Feb 23 14:28 flvr-shb.prf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  320211 Feb 23 14:28 graf-shb.prf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   54201 Feb 23 14:28 Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  118224 Feb 23 14:28 xtra-shb.prf
```

What do I need to do in order to use graphical tiles in Angband 3.5.1 (in Ubuntu 18.10)?